# Conditional attributes in React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I just wrote some ugly code.  Can someone show me the better way to do it?  Here's the pseudocode:

```
let btn;

if(this.props.href && !this.props.onClick && !this.props.dataMsg etc...)
btn = <a href={this.props.href}>{this.props.text}</a>;


else if(!this.props.href && this.props.onClick && !this.props.dataMsg etc...)
btn = <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</a>;

etc...

else if(this.props.href && this.props.onClick && !this.props.dataMsg etc...)
btn = <a href={this.props.href} onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</a>;

else if(!this.props.href && this.props.onClick && this.props.dataMsg etc...)
btn = <a onClick={this.props.onClick} data-msg={this.props.dataMsg}>{this.props.text}</a>;

etc...
```

In other words, I want to set the attributes of the `<a>` element only if the react component received a props for it.   However, not all props of the react component are meant to be an attribute, some of it could be `this.props.text` which belongs in the innerHTML.

There must be a less verbose way to write what I want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> React will ignore all the attribute which has `undefined` as its value.

So, you don't need to use `if` conditions. Instead, you can check for the value attribute and return `undefined` if you don't get the value.

For Example:

You can write you code as follows,

```
<a
  href={this.props.href} //returns undefined if href not present in props
  onClick={this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick} //set callback if it is present in the props
  data-msg={this.props.dataMsg} //returns undefined if href not present in props
>
 {this.props.text}
</a>;
```

Returning `undefined` to any attributes makes React to ignore those attributes.

Hope it helps!